# Passing a vector as a reference to a function

Tags: c++, vector, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I'm trying to do the simply task of passing a vector to a function as a reference, and the modify the vector within the function.
However, I get some pretty incomprehensible errors with the following example:

```
// data.h
class data {
public:
  std::string a;
  double b;
  uint8_t c;
};
```

We make a vector of these data objects in the MainWindow class:

```
// MainWindow.h
class MainWindow {
public:
  std::vector<data> vec;
  void needs_vec(std::vector<data> &vec);
};
```

Below I've got the troublemaker function, along with the constructor of the MainWindow object which is where everything comes together.

```
// other_file.h
void needs_vec(std::vector<data> &vec) {
  for (auto &vec: vec) {
    vec.b = get_a_number();
  }
};

// MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow() {
  // Read a configuration file and initialize the vector
  this->vec = read_config();

  // Try to apply our function
  needs_vec(this->vec);

  // Continue doing other things
};
```

I've also tried playing around with rvalue references but I meet similar results: an indecipherable twenty page error message.

Comment: `vec.double = get_a_number();` This is like a big pointing arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `data` doesn't have a `double` value called `double`, but `b`.

**Apply these changes:**

```
void MainWindow::needs_vec(std::vector<data> &vec) {
  for (auto &vec: vec) {      // Change the name here
    vec.b = get_a_number();
  }
}
```

Furthermore, are you closing your classes with a closing brace and semicolon, `};`?

E.g

```
// data.h
class data {
public:
  string a;
  double b;
  uint8_t c;
} /* including ";"?? */
```

Comment: Calling them the same name isn't really a problem as per C++ goes.

Comment: The compiler is the only one not confused.

Comment: No, you use `->` when you have a pointer. `vec` is a reference. Just switch it back to `vec.b`. The second point in its entirety is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a few errors when copying my code over from my actual program and removing the extraneous code. I've made an edit correcting them now.

Comment: @nov1943 Did it work? If so, could you please mark the question as correct?